# Worklight dojo heading labels are duplicated

Tags: dojo, ibm-mobilefirst

When working with dojo in Worklight, my heading labels appear twice (are duplicated).

**index.html**

```
<div 
    id="info"
    data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.Heading" 
    data-dojo-props='label:"User Information"'
    style = "background-color: silver; font-size: 20px;">
</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: can your provide some code ?

Answer (score 0):

I've changed your code snippet to the following and it works for me w/out any duplication.
Note the slight change to data-dojo-props with the quotation marks.

```
<div 
    id="info"
    data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.Heading"
    data-dojo-props="label:'User Information'"
    style = "background-color: silver; font-size: 20px;">
</div>
```

I've created a new Worklight project and application with Dojo (using the Worklight Hybrid Application wizard) and added to it the modified code snippet. I see only 1 header.

**My index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title>dojotest</title>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
            <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
            <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.png">
            <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/apple-touch-icon.png">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
            <script>window.$ = window.jQuery = WLJQ;</script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="dojox/mobile/deviceTheme.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" data-dojo-config="isDebug: false, async: true, parseOnLoad: true, mblHideAddressBar: false" src="dojo/dojo.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body style="display: none;">
            <div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ScrollableView" id="view0" data-dojo-props="selected:true">
                <div 
                    id="info"
                    data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.Heading" 
                    data-dojo-props="label:'User Information'"
                    style = "background-color: silver; font-size: 20px;">
                </div>
            </div>
            <script src="js/initOptions.js"></script>
            <script src="js/main.js"></script>
            <script src="js/messages.js"></script>
        </body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry it doesn't work for me :( Maybe I have a problem in .js file? function dojoInit() {
 require([ "dojo/ready", "dojo/_base/kernel", "dojo/parser","dojox/mobile", "dojo/dom", "dijit/registry", "dojox/mobile/ScrollableView", "dojox/mobile/TabBarButton", "dojox/mobile/TextArea", "dojox/mobile/TextBox", "dojox/mobile/Button", "dojox/dgauges/components/default/SemiCircularLinearGauge" ], function(ready) {
  ready(function() {
  });
 });
}